# Epsilon delta proof for a limit approaching infinity

Tags: limits, proof-verification

I have to prove that the limit as x approaches infinity of $$(1/x+1)^{((ln 5)/(ln 1/x + 1))} = 5.$$ Is my proof valid?
$$
\\ \text{Definition for limit as x} \rightarrow \text{infinity:}
\\ \forall\ \epsilon >0\ \exists\ R > 0\ \text{such that}\ \forall\ x>R, |f(x)-L|<\epsilon
\\
\\
\
\\Proof:
\\ |f(x)-L| < \epsilon
\\
\\|(\frac{1}{x}+1)^{\frac{ln5}{ln \frac{1}{x}+1}} -5|< \epsilon
\\
\\ \epsilon + 5 <(\frac{1}{x}+1)^{\frac{ln5}{ln \frac{1}{x}+1}} < \epsilon + 5
\\
\\ (\frac{1}{x}+1) < (\epsilon +5)^{\frac{ln \frac{1}{x}+1}{ln5}}
\\
\\ \frac{1}{x} < (\epsilon +5)^{\frac{ln \frac{1}{x}+1}{ln5}}-1
\\ \
\\ x > \frac{1}{(\epsilon +5)^{\frac{ln \frac{1}{x}+1}{ln5}}-1}
\\ \
\\ Let R = \frac{1}{(\epsilon +5)^{\frac{ln \frac{1}{x}+1}{ln5}}-1}
\\ \
\\ \ \therefore x > R
$$

Comment: Your definition of $R$ depends on $x.$ So it is a bit circular, whether there actually exists an $x>R$  Furthermore,  It is not clear that this proves that the limit is uniquely 5.  It seems that you could could use the same algebra to show $\lim_\limits{x\to \infty} f(x) = 6.$  If the limit isn't unique, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Aren't I using the correct definition of epsilon-delta limits? If I am, how is there a huge hole in my reasoning?

Comment: You have the correct definition.  But, you want to find $R$ in terms of $\epsilon$ only.  However, in this case I would suggest that instead you prove that your function is a constant function.

Comment: How do I prove that it is a constant function? To be honest, just looking at the function, I wouldn't realize that it is one, but I saw the graph so I know it all works out.

Comment: I figured it out, I can just evaluate the function and prove that the function is equal to 5.

Comment: You have a typo in the 3rd line , where the far LHS should be $-\epsilon +5$. Your method requires showing that both inequalities hold for all sufficeienty large $x.$

Comment: An easier method would be to take the logarithm of the original expression and use the fact that  $\log (1+1/x)=(1/x)(1+g(x))$ where $g(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty.$